# Transferring files with metadata

Tags: c#, xml, ftp, transfer

I am writing a client windows app which will allow files and respective metadata to be uploaded to a server. For example gear.stl (original file) and gear.stl.xml (metadata).  I am trying to figure out the correct protcol to use to transfer the files.

I was thinking about using ftp since it is widely used and a proven method to transfer files, except that I would have to transfer 2 files for every actual file (.stl and .stl.xml).  However, another thought had also crossed my mind ... What if I create an object and wrap the file, metadata and the directory I needed to tranfer it to, serialize the object and then submit a request to a webservice, to transfer the file.

Original file size would range from 100k to 10MB.  Metadata size would probably be less than 200k

The webservice call seems like an easier process to me to deserialize the object and distribute the file and respective metadata accordingly.  However I'm not sure if this is a sound idea or if there is a better way to transfer this data other than the two methods I have mentioned.

If someone can point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap it in a zip file like the "new" office document format does. You might even be able to use their classes to package it all up.

**Edit:**

Take a look at the [System.IO.Packaging.Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.package.aspx) class. It seems to be what you need. This class resides in the WindowsBase.dll assembly and became available in .NET 3.0.

PS: Remember that even though it is a zip file, it doesn't need to be compressed. If you have very large files, it may be better to keep them uncompressed. It all depends on how they're going to be used and if the transport size is an issue.